# User input dropdown list sanitization in drupal 7

Tags: search, database, forms

For Drupal 7.
I  am using a custom search form with more than 6 drop-downs. I would like to sanitize the user select value before passing to the query.Now a days there are many tools available to edit the option value and inject some malicious codes(Firebug etc.).

I tried to validate user input by  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['field_value']);But mysql_real_escape_string  returns no output or not working .May i know what is the real issue?.Could you please help me to validate user inputs?

thanks...
hary

Comment: Are you using the Form API to build your form? If so, you're covered - it already checks option lists to make sure the provided value was one of the original list. You'll get an 'Illegal choice detected' error otherwise and validation will fail. Drupal doesn't use the deprecated `mysql_*` family of functions (thankfully) which is why `mysql_real_escape_string()` doesn't do what you expect

Comment: Thanks for the real information.I'm not using a Form API .I'm frank,i don't know how to create a form using Form API ! I need to set 6 drop down fields as my search conditions.So 6 fields are used for searching.How could i build a form with this?Could you please help me to do this if you have enough time.please send me some help topics to find a proper solution.

thank you again and i hope that you can help me.

Comment: There's no better place to start than the [Examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples), specifically the [Form API example module](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example!form_example.module/group/form_example/7). Trust me when I say the benefits of using the form API far outweigh the benefits of adding forms manually. You won't even need to consider this sanitisation issue, CSRF is handled automatically, etc.

Comment: ok...
So its better to start with the example module first.Let me try this.
thanks you very much.